# Blocking access to html page while user edits

Tags: python, html, django

I have a Django web app for booking golf competition times for members. Once logged in, all users have ability to edit player names for each time. These are then manually reset for the following week after the competition. The issue is if more than 1 user edits at the same time, it will save last instance and others will not realize.
I have the list of times, (with 4 name slots each), on one html page with an edit button for each time, which leads to a separate html page for editing those 4 names.
Is there anyway of blocking a html page once opened by 1 user? Or a thought I had was to create a button next to "Edit", which changes color and text, (green to red, and "Open" to "Edit in progress" for example), for a set period or until "save" button clicked on update page.
Here is the relevant code-
Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
time=models.CharField(max_length=50)
player1=models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Player 1")
player2=models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Player 2")
player3=models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Player 3")
player4=models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Player 4")

def __str__(self):
    return self.time
```

Views.py

```
def teetimes(request):
posts=Post.objects.all()
name=CompNames.objects.get(id=1)
return render(request, 'memtees/teetimes.html', {'posts':posts, 'name':name})

def add(request):
if request.method=='POST':
    time=request.POST['time']
    player1=request.POST['player1']
    player2=request.POST['player2']
    player3=request.POST['player3']
    player4=request.POST['player4']
    Post.objects.create(time=time,player1=player1,player2=player2,player3=player3,player4=player4)
    messages.success(request,'New Time has been added')
return render(request,'memtees/add.html')

def update(request,id):
if request.method=='POST':
    time=request.POST['time']
    player1=request.POST['player1']
    player2=request.POST['player2']
    player3=request.POST['player3']
    player4=request.POST['player4']
    Post.objects.filter(id=id).update(time=time,player1=player1,player2=player2,player3=player3,player4=player4)
    messages.success(request,'Information has been updated, return to Tee-Times to view ')
post=Post.objects.get(id=id)
return render(request,'memtees/update.html',{'post':post})

def clear_players(request):
Post.objects.all().update(player1="", player2="", player3="", player4="")
return redirect('/memtees/teetimes')

def delete(request,id):
Post.objects.filter(id=id).delete()
return redirect('/memtees/teetimes')
```

Full list of times HTML

```
    {% for post in posts|dictsort:"time" %}
    <div>
        <table style="background-color:white" class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>                       
                <th colspan="4" style="margin:0" padding="0"><h7>{{post.time}} &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="{% url 'update0' post.id %}"  class="btn-sm btn-success">Update</a></h7></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 25%"><p style="font-size:small; margin-bottom:0">{{post.player1}}</p></td>
                <td style="width: 25%"><p style="font-size:small; margin-bottom:0">{{post.player2}}</p></td>
                <td style="width: 25%"><p style="font-size:small; margin-bottom:0">{{post.player3}}</p></td>
                <td style="width: 25%"><p style="font-size:small; margin-bottom:0">{{post.player4}}</p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

For editing names and saving HTML

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <td>
                        <input value="{{post.time}}" type="text" name="time" class="form-control" readonly>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Player 1</th>
                    <td>
                        <input value="{{post.player1}}" type="text" name="player1" class="form-control"  onclick="player1.select()">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Player 2</th>
                    <td>
                        <input value="{{post.player2}}" type="text" name="player2" class="form-control"  onclick="player2.select()">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Player 3</th>
                    <td>
                        <input value="{{post.player3}}" type="text" name="player3" class="form-control"  onclick="player3.select()">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Player 4</th>
                    <td>
                        <input value="{{post.player4}}" type="text" name="player4" class="form-control"  onclick="player4.select()">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
                      
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: This is a matter of the data model and flow the booking goes through. At first `time` should not be free text field. I would use an extra model `Slots` which are create in advance and the user can choose from. When chosen the slot will be reserved for some time in which the user can fill in additional data. If he doesn't, the reservation will be dropped.

Comment: The best I was able to manage was adding a warning to the time-slot, so that when a user clicks "Update", text is added to the slot that notifies other users it is currently being updated. This warning disappears when updates are saved, or a time of 5 minutes passes.